# How to detect Scroll Bar in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, scrollbar

I am using `QListWidget` as with horizoantal orientation. I purposefully set `setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);`

I want to show two buttons (one for scroll left and one to scroll right) when my items are more that list's visual width.

So my question is how can I detect such condition? because I want to show these buttons when I need scrolling, for rest of time they should remain hidden.

How Qt decides when to show scroll bars?

Comment: Why not `setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);`?

Comment: actually I do not want scroll bar because of fixed height of QListWidget . Instead I placed two buttons ( one at begin and other at end) in layout with QListWidget. I want to show/hide these button when I need scroll. in fact I want to use these button as replacement of scroll bar.